# C*-Algebras and Operator Theory - Gerald J. Murphy Theorem 4.1.2

Tags: operator-theory, c-star-algebras, projection

I'm stuck On the theorem**Theorem 4.1.2**, from   C*-Algebras and Operator Theory by Gerald J. Murphy

> **4.1.2. Theorem.** Suppose that $(p_\lambda)_{\lambda\in\Lambda}$ is a net of projections on a Hilbert space $H$.
>
> (1) If $(p_\lambda)$ is increasing, then it is strongly convergent to the projection of $H$ onto the closed vector subspace $(\cup_{\lambda}p_\lambda(H))^-$.
>
> (2) If $(p_\lambda)$ is decreasing, then it is strongly convergent to the projection of $H$ onto $\cap_\lambda p_\lambda(H)$.

I have no idea how to deal with. Any hints or suggestions
would be welcome!

Comment: by increasing you mean $p_\lambda (H) \subset p_\eta (H)$ for $\lambda \le \eta$?

Comment: @ Targon , yes that is I mean

Comment: Hello user62498, I wonder why you are presenting a mere PSQ, suffixed by "I have no idea ..."$-$
cf. [Avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27933/316749),
$-$ given that you're an experienced math.SE user (with rep $>3k$). 
For these reasons I vote to close the post.

Comment: Dear Hanno, I'm so sorry You are right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As established earlier in Murphy, an increasing net of projections that is bounded above by a self-adjoint element converges strongly to its supremum. Hence, for $(1)$ we must check that if $p$ is the projection onto $K= \overline{\bigcup_\lambda p_\lambda H}$, then $p$ is the supremum of the net $\{p_\lambda\}$.

This is rather easy, since $p \geq p_\lambda$ for all $\lambda$ because $pH \supseteq p_\lambda H$ by definition of $p$. Thus $p$ is an upper bound for this net.

Moreover, if $q \geq p_\lambda$ for all $\lambda$, then clearly $q \geq p$ and
$$(p-q)p_\lambda = pp_\lambda-q p_\lambda = p_\lambda- p_\lambda = 0$$
so that $p-q$ annihilates the subspace $K$. Hence,
$$0 = (p-q)p = p-qp= p-q$$
and thus $q=p$. Thus, $p$ is the least upperbound. Can you now do $(2)$ yourself?

Comment: Thank you very much QuantumSpace, you are brilliant!